# i am trying to take user input and display with a condition that it should be Alphabet

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    
    String name;
    System.out.println("Please Enter Name");
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    //s.nextLine();
    name=s.nextLine();
    if(isAlpha(name)) {
        System.out.println("Name is: " +name);
    }else {
        System.out.println("please Enter valid name");
    }
    
    }
    
    public static boolean isAlpha(String name) {
        char[] charArray = name.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
           char ch = charArray[i];
           if (!(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) {
              return false;
           }
           else if (!(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')) {
                  return false;
               }
           else {
               return true;
           }
        }
        return true;
        
    }
```

i am trying to take user input and display it only if it satisfy a condition that it should contain alphabets only but it shows every entry as invalid why?

Comment: I think you meant to say that it should contain *letters* only.

Comment: Your code will return `false` is the character is not `a-z` *or* not `A-Z`. Since it can't be both at the same time, it will always return `false`. You need to check if the character is not `a-z` *and* not `A-Z`. Also, you shouldn't return `true` from inside the loop, because when you do, you ensure that it only checks the first character, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
public static boolean isAlpha(String s) {
        return s != null && s.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$");
    }
```

Comment: can i go with the same method for "Phone Number" i.e Numbers only:

Comment: By changing[a-zA-Z] to[0-9]??

Comment: @GOURAVUPADHYAY If someone's helped you with a problem, accept their answer. Don't add new requirements.

Comment: yes changing it to [0-9] will work for numeric values but phone number has a specific length depending upon the country so that will also have to take in to account

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a character that is both uppercase & lowercase so one of your if blocks will always return `false` in the `isAlpha` method. Instead you could do

```
public static boolean isAlpha(String name) {
    char[] charArray = name.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        char ch = charArray[i];
        if (!(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')) {
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```